Langchain Pandas agent returns SyntaxError while analyzing dataframe
I'm encountering a SyntaxError when using the Pandas dataframe agent in a loop. It seems that the LLM (Large Language Model) is not correctly using the python_repl_ast tool. Here are a few examples of the errors I'm getting:

Example 1:

Action Input: import pandas as pd\ndf = pd.read_csv('datasets/titanic/train.csv')\ndf['Ticket'].head()
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character (<unknown>, line 1)

It seems there was an error in the execution due to incorrect formatting of the input. Let's correct the format and try to load the dataset and examine the 'Ticket' column again.


Example 2:

Action: python_repl_ast
Action Input: import numpy as np\nnp.save('columns/SibSp.npy', df['SibSp'].values)
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character (<unknown>, line 1)

It seems there was a mistake in my approach to executing the command due to syntax issues. Let's correct the syntax by removing the newline escape characters and try again to save the 'SibSp' column as a numpy array.

How I create agent:
llm = ChatOpenAI(
        temperature=0.0,
        model_name='gpt-4-turbo-preview',
        max_tokens=1024)
    agent = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(llm, prefix=PREPROCESS_PREFIX, df=df, verbose=True,
                                          input_variables=['column', 'file_path'],
                                          handle_parsing_errors=True,           return_intermediate_steps=True)

How can I prevent these SyntaxError issues when the LLM attempts to use the python_repl_ast tool in the agent? Is there a way to ensure the correct formatting of the input to avoid these errors? Should I better describe usage of python_repl_ast in LLM prompt ? I'm using
The occurrence of the error seems random. The solution should modify all columns of the dataframe in a loop. I want to avoid SyntaxErrors because they interrupt the execution of my program and consume tokens without returning concrete answers.
